# How to refresh the contents within the Python TKINTER Tab?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, refresh, mysql-python

I have a program that displays some data from MySQL using Treeview. I would like to update the contents of it using a "refresh button" instead of terminating and re-running the program again. I have tried self.destroy() function, but it closes the tab and doesn't reopen the tab. Are there other ways to just refresh the Treeview?

```
class tab_four(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
...

       #tree.heading("#0", text = " ")
        tree.heading("1", text = "Equipment Type")
        tree.heading("2", text = "Total")
        tree.heading("3", text = "Unavailable")
        tree.heading("4", text = "Available")  
        
        #tree.column('#0', stretch = NO, minwidth = 0, width = 0)
        tree.column('#1', stretch = YES, minwidth = 0, width = 100, anchor = CENTER)
        tree.column('#2', stretch = YES, minwidth = 0, width = 100, anchor = CENTER)
        tree.column('#3', stretch = YES, minwidth = 0, width = 100, anchor = CENTER)
        tree.column('#4', stretch = YES, minwidth = 0, width = 100, anchor = CENTER)  
                      
        command = "SELECT et.`Equipment Type`, COUNT(i.`Equipment Type`) Total, SUM(IF(`Status`='Unavailable',1,0)) Unavailable, SUM(IF(`Status`='Available',1,0)) Available FROM `Equipment Types` et LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON et.`Equipment Type` = i.`Equipment Type` GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1"
        mycursor.execute(command)
        display = mycursor.fetchall()

        for row in display:
            tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
            
    def refresh_clicked(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.__init__()
        
        button_refresh = tk.Button(topframe, text = "Refresh", state = NORMAL, command = self.refresh_clicked)
        button_refresh.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 2)
```

[image: refresh]

[image: edited]
[image: edited2]

Comment: You are not supposed to update the question with answers given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fetch the values again and then insert the new values after deleting the existing values, like:

```py
def refresh_clicked(self):
    command = """SELECT et.`Equipment Type`, COUNT(i.`Equipment Type`) Total, SUM(IF(`Status`='Unavailable',1,0)) Unavailable, SUM(IF(`Status`='Available',1,0)) Available FROM `Equipment Types` et LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON et.`Equipment Type` = i.`Equipment Type` GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1"""
    mycursor.execute(command)
    display = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children()) # Delete all times inside the treeview
    
    for row in display:
        self.tree.insert('','end',value=row) # Insert newly fetched values
```

Note that I used `self.tree`, so you need to declare the `Treeview` with `self.tree` and do all other methods with `self.tree` and so on.

Comment: I got this error:    tree.delete(*tree.get_children()) # Delete all times inside the treeview
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined

Comment: @Daniel Oh yes, of course, you have to define tree as `self.tree` in the `__init__()` then use, `self.tree.delete(....)` and so on.

Comment: It works after I changed everything from tree to self.tree. But I didn't change anything in the  __init__().

Comment: You have to change every `tree` to `self.tree`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```py
for widgets in yourwidgetname.winfo_children():
    widgets.destroy()
```

and reinitialize it by calling the function that initialize them

you can destroy all the widgets in a Frame by this way and it wont destroy completely your frame. it will destroy its child widgets.